# Iron man thrusters with realism

Tags: particles, effects

I was making a simple iron man animation for one of my projects.
Now,i wanted to make him fly. For that,i need to make his thrusters.
This is the what i am trying to make--

[[image][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XQL6u.jpg)

After messing around with particles,quick smoke and quick fire effects,i managed to make this thing--

[image]

Which i know does not look that good. Even though its rendered in eevee,using cycles does not help either.

How can i make something like picture 1 in blender. Also,it has to be sort of movable(i want a video not a still image).

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Another way of doing this is using the shader editor. It saves a lot of computation and baking time to! Here you have a tutorial that explain it really well: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WZ1ghoVPdEg&ab_channel=SirFloof

Comment: Its good. I might try that,but still,waiting for more responses.

Comment: The answer by @Artichoke is quite good. You're not gonna get that desired look with a fire simulation. Typical jet turbine exhaust speeds are about 2000 kilometers per hour, which means if you want to simulate the fire shooting out downwards for example you would have to set the velocity on the flow object to -555 m/s on Z axis, which is much too fast to get a good, smooth simulation without having a very high resolution and lots of timesteps for calculation.

Comment: Ya i understood fire simulation is not the way to go. But what i meant by wait for more responses is that i am trying to find something that looks much more similar to the referance image above. If i didn't found any more responses,then his answer is the way to go

Comment: It shouldn't be too hard to make small changes to the nodes to get what you want by following the same tutorial.

Comment: And to be fair, if you just want a photo, maybe you can add those fire effects in after effects or in a software to edit photos...

Comment: Ya,i will experiment with it a bit to get desired look. And i cant use AE method because its not just one picture.